# PHP Insert tabs in front of numbers/decimals and format them neatly

Tags: php, preg-replace, decimal

I have string (text, numbers, punctuation, etc.) that I want to format in a specific style.

**I have this:**

```
1. TOC 1.1 Chapter 1.1 1.2 Chapter 1.2 1.3 Chapter 1.3 2. Automation 2.1 This is Chapter 2.1 2.2 Chapter 2.2 is it's name 3. Mechanics 3.1 Chapter 3.2 Some Chapter 3.2a Sub-chapter of 3.2 3.2b Sub-chapter of 3.2 chapter
```

**Need this:**

```
  1. TOC
    1.1 Chapter 1.1
    1.2 Chapter 1.2
    1.3 Chapter 1.3

  2. Automation
    2.1 This is Chapter 2.1
    2.2 Chapter 2.2 is it's name

  3. Mechanics
    3.1 Chapter 
    3.2 Some Chapter 
        3.2a Sub-chapter of 3.2
        3.2b Sub-chapter of 3.2 chapter
```

**Tried this:**

```
$text = preg_replace('/([0-9])/', "\n\t$1", $text);
```

**Got this (incorrect output):**

```
1. TOC

1.
1 Chapter 
1.
1

1.
2 Chapter 
1.
2

1.
3 Chapter 
1.
3


2. Automation

2.
1 This is Chapter 
2.
1

2.
2 Chapter 
2.
2 is it's name


3. Mechanics

3.
1 Chapter 

3.
2 Some Chapter 

3.
2a Sub-chapter of 
3.
2

3.
2b Sub-chapter of 
3.
2 chapter
```

How can this be fixed so that the output is displayed in the format that I need?

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying this in a browser? Standard text whitespace characters are all treated as spaces, and repeatd whitespace chars are collapsed into a single displayed char.

As well, your regex won't work for this. It's looking for any **SINGLE** digit and prefacing it with a newline/tab. You have to look for the whole digit pattern, e,g. `/(\d\.\d[a-z]?)/`

Comment: I am trying to display this in a textarea. I will then copy it from the text area into my document. I tried your code & right now they all have just one tab. How can I indent the sub-chapters as shown?